# How to disable and enable Delete button if checkbox is not checked in GridView by Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want to disable and enable Delete button if checkbox is not checked in GridView by Jquery?
This is my code which doesn't work.

Please help me in a simple way because I am a new developer!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function () {

                       $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('input[Id*="CheckBox1"]:checkbox').click(function() {
                           if  (this.checked ==true) 
                           {
                               $('[id$="Button2"]').attr('disabled',false);

                           }
                           else
                           {
                               $('[id$="Button2"]').attr('disabled',true);
                           }
                       })
                   });
        </script>
```

Comment: use css classes to manipulate the DOM objects .. in case of DataBound Controls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to check if the checkbox is checked -

```
<input id="checkbox"  type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" checked="checked">
```

--

```
// First method - Recommended
$('#checkbox').prop('checked')  // Boolean true

// Second method - Makes code more readable (e.g. in if statements)
$('#checkbox').is(':checked')  // Boolean true

// Third method - Selecting the checkbox & filtering by :checked selector
$('#checkbox:checked').length  // Integer >0
$('#checkbox:checked').size()  // .size() can be used instead of .length

// Fourth method - Getting DOM object reference
$('#checkbox').get(0).checked  // Boolean true
$('#checkbox')[0].checked      // Boolean true (same as above)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript you should use:

```
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr td input[id*="CheckBox1"][type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input[id*="Button2"]');
    if ($(this).prop("checked") === true) {
        btn.attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        btn.attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Regards,
Uros

Comment: do i have to call this function onclient click ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function onCheckBoxChecked(obj) {
  var btn = $(obj).closest('tr').find('input[id*="Button2"]');
  var isChecked = $(obj).attr('checked') ? true : false;
  if (isChecked)
    btn.attr("disabled", false);
 else
    btn.attr("disabled", true);
}
```

and add onclick event in the gridview checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" onclick="onCheckBoxChecked(this);" runat="server">
                                </asp:CheckBox>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092743/how-to-disable-a-button-when-all-the-checkboxes-in-grid-are-disable-or-un-checke/44092853?noredirect=1#comment75207474_44092853