# how to disable a button when all the checkboxes in grid are disable or un checked using JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

> I have a grid in which I have 1 coulmns has `checkboxes`.I want to 
>   disable a button when all the checkbox are disabled or unticked(uncheked) 
>   using JavaScript or jQuery?

**.Aspx File**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cancel SO Line Item">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:checkbox ID="cbSOCan" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true"></asp:checkbox>
         </ItemTemplate>

     <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnCancelItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"OnClientClick="return Confirmationbox();">&nbsp;Cancel Item</asp:LinkButton>
 <asp:HiddenField id="hdnval" value=0 runat="server"/>
```

[image: GRID]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following, but you'll need to update it with more specific selectors so it doesn't affect all checkboxes and buttons:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqsordzb/1/)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $('button').prop('disabled', count == 0);
});
```

And if you need it on load as well:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqsordzb/2/)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    disableCheckbox();
});

disableCheckbox = function() {
    var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $('button').prop('disabled', count == 0);
};

disableCheckbox();
```

Comment: Its just affecting DOM elements, so it should be able to [client side](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_client_side.htm). Would need to see how the html is in the DOM.